# Create circuit using circuitikz or something else

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, circuitikz

I would like to make a circuit like this: [image]

but I'm struggling. As far as I know the thing on the right (light bulb) is just omega with the line drawn through the circle. I would except something like this be simple but I'm really struggling. I'm not really sure why we do circuit diagrams like this in discrete maths, it seems to be really non-standard (I can't find anything like it on google!), but the professors managed to typeset it in LaTeX so it must be possible!. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have tried so far? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`. In order to compile with `pdflatex`, you should launch the compile with the `-shell-escape` switch under TeX Live or MacTeX, `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-circ}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{fourier}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\psset{dimen=middle, linejoin=1, labeloffset=0}
\begin{pspicture}%
\pnodes(0,0){O}(0,3){A}(2,3){P}(7,3){Q}(9,3){B}(9,0){C}%
(2.5,3.7){A1}(4,3.7){P1}(5,3.7){Q1}(6.5,3.7){B1}%
(2.5,2.3){A2}(4,2.3){P2}(5,2.3){Q2}(6.5,2.3){B2}%
\battery(A)(O){}
\psline(A)(P)(A1)(P)(A2)
\circledipole(A1)(P1){$ x $}\wire(P1)(Q1)\circledipole(Q1)(B1){$y'$}
\circledipole(A2)(P2){$ x' $}\wire(P2)(Q2)\circledipole(Q2)(B2){$y$}
\psline(B1)(Q)(B2)(Q)(B)
\Ucc[dipolestyle=normalCei, labeloffset=4.5pt](B)(C){\rotateright{$ \Omega $}}
\wire(C)(AQ)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with circuitiz/tikz.  I think the symbol on the right is supposed to be a light bulb.  (I could easily create one.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (0,2) to[battery1] (0,0);
\node[draw,circle,name=x] at (2,3) {\strut $x$};
\node[draw,thin,circle,name=xp] at (2,1) {\strut $x'$};
\node[draw,circle,name=yp] at (4,3) {\strut $y'$};
\node[draw,circle,name=y] at (4,1) {\strut $y$};
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (x) -- (yp) -- (5,2);
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (xp) -- (y) -- (5,2);
\draw[thick] (5,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,0) -- (0,0);
\node[draw,circle] at (6,1) {\strut};
\node[rotate=-90,above,inner sep=0pt] at(6,1) {$\Omega$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]